# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source') possible problem with async

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to javascript and I'm trying to set up an ecommerce shop. However, whenever I try to view the page locally, I am met with this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')`

Here is my App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { commerce } from './lib/commerce';
//import Products from './components/Products/Products';
//import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';

import { Products, Navbar } from './components';

const App = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    const fetchProducts = async () => {
        const { data } = await commerce.products.list();

        setProducts(data);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchProducts();
    }, []);


    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Products products={products} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Here is Products.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

import Product from './Product/Product';
import useStyles from './styles';



const Products = ({ products }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();


    return(
        <main className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />
            <Grid container justify= "center" spacing ={4}>

            {products.map((product) => (

                <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                        <Product product={product} />
                    </Grid>

            ))};

            </Grid>



        </main>
    )

}

export default Products;
```

Here is Product.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardMedia, CardContent, CardActions, Typography, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import { AddShoppingCart } from '@material-ui/icons';
// import { classes } from 'istanbul-lib-coverage';


import useStyles from './styles';

const Product = ({ product }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();


    return (
        <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={product.media.source} title={product.name}/>
            <CardContent>
                <div className={classes.CardContent}>
                    <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                        {product.name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h5">
                        {product.price.formatted_with_symbol}
                    </Typography>
                </div>
                <Typography variant ="body2" color="textSecondary">{product.description}</Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.CardActions}>
                <IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart">
                    <AddShoppingCart />
                </IconButton>
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
    )
}

export default Product
```

I believe the problem could have something to do with the async function, however I'm not sure. I think the setProducts function is not getting the proper data. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the data

```
const { data } = await commerce.products.list();
```

The data should be

```
[
 {
   media: { source: value, ...}
   ...
 },
 ...
]
```